# How to optimize union all statements

Tags: vertica

I want range result to display it on chart.
I prepared following query: (for vertica)

`select count(a_date) as value FROM table_data  where a_date >= '2003-10-23' and a_date < '2007-01-01'
union all
select count(a_date) as value FROM table_data  where a_date >= '2007-01-01' and a_date < '2010-04-03'
union all
select count(a_date) as value FROM table_data  where a_date >= '2010-04-03' and a_date < '2013-07-02'
union all
select count(a_date) as value FROM  table_data  where a_date >= '2013-07-02' and a_date < '2016-10-01'
union all
select  count(a_date) as value FROM table_data  where a_date >= '2016-10-01' and a_date <= '12-10-2019'`

It is taking a lot of time as table_data contains huge records.

Is there any fast way

Answer (score 3):

I would try to avoid using `UNION ALL` statements if you can help it. One way to get around this would be to create a calendar dimension table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE cal_date_dim
(
        id INT,
        cal_date DATE,
        cal_date_year INT,
        date_range_id INT
)
ORDER BY cal_date
UNSEGMENTED ALL NODES;



INSERT INTO cal_date_dim (id, cal_date, cal_date_year, date_range_id) VALUES (DAYS('2003-10-20'), '2003-10-20', YEAR('2003-10-20'::DATE), 0);

/* Run this 6000 times, or as many times as is needed to populate the table */
INSERT INTO cal_date_dim (id, cal_date, cal_date_year, date_range_id)
SELECT DAYS(next_date), next_date, YEAR(next_date), 0 
FROM (
        SELECT MAX(cal_date) + 1 next_date
        FROM cal_date_dim
) n;


UPDATE cal_date_dim SET date_range_id = 1 WHERE cal_date >= '2003-10-23' and cal_date < '2007-01-01';
UPDATE cal_date_dim SET date_range_id = 2 WHERE cal_date >= '2007-01-01' and cal_date < '2010-04-03';
UPDATE cal_date_dim SET date_range_id = 3 WHERE cal_date >= '2010-04-03' and cal_date < '2013-07-02';
UPDATE cal_date_dim SET date_range_id = 4 WHERE cal_date >= '2013-07-02' and cal_date < '2016-10-01';
UPDATE cal_date_dim SET date_range_id = 5 WHERE cal_date >= '2016-10-01' and cal_date <= '2019-12-10';
```

In the code block above I created a generic calendar dimension table. You can create more columns such as `cal_date_month`, `cal_date_quarter`, `cal_date_day`, etc. if you want to expand this logic.

To populate the table, I ran a single `INSERT` statement with a static date value, then I ran the second `INSERT` statement about 6000 times to make sure I had all dates covered.

I then updated the column `date_range_id` based on the values you are trying to group by.

---

With this dimension table in place, you can now join the `table_data` table to the new `cal_date_dim` calendar dimension table with the following query:

```sql
SELECT value
FROM (
        SELECT c.date_range_id, COUNT(a_date) value
        FROM
                table_data t
                LEFT JOIN cal_date_dim c
                        ON t.a_date = c.cal_date
        WHERE c.date_range_id > 0
        GROUP BY c.date_range_id
) x;
```

This will return the same result as your `UNION ALL` query from above, and should be more performant.

If the date ranges you supplied above are not static, but always changing, you may still have better performance by creating the `cal_date_dim` table anyway, but specify the `date_range_id` with `CASE` statements.

```sql
SELECT cal_date, CASE WHEN cal_date >= '2019-12-11' and a_date < '2020-02-03' THEN 1 WHEN ... END as date_range_id
FROM cal_date_dim
```

Joining the `table_data` table to the above as a subquery may still be more performant than doing several `UNION ALL` statements, even if the `date_range_id` is evaluated dynamically.

---

**NOTE:**
Observe that the `cal_date_dim` table's superprojection is sorted by `cal_date`. Since you are joining `cal_date` to `table_data.a_date`, the above query will perform significantly faster if you create a projection for the table `table_data` that has `a_date` as the first `ORDER BY` column. To optimize the query even further, consider segmenting by `a_date`.

```sql
CREATE PROJECTION table_data_date_sorted
(
  a_date,
  ...
)
AS
  SELECT
    a_date,
    ...
  FROM table_data
  ORDER BY
    a_date,
    ...
SEGMENTED BY HASH(a_date) ALL NODES;
```